# in ionic i am not able to fetch data from json file

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am not able to fetch json file data 
here is my code please help me to solve this problem
html code is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title></title>

       <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/data.json"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="starter">

    <ion-pane>
      <ion-header-bar class="bar-dark">
        <h2 class="title">Artist List</h2>
      </ion-header-bar>

  <div class="bar bar-subheader
      item-input-inset bar-light">
     <label class="item-input-wrapper">
        <i class="icon ion-search"></i>
        <input type="search" placeholder="Search">
     </label>
  </div>

      <ion-content ng-controller="ListController"
      class="has-subheader">
        <ion-list>
          <ion-item ng-repeat='item in artists'
           class="item-thumbnail-left item-text-wrap">
          <img src="img/{{item.shortname}}_tn.jpg" alt="{{item.name}} Photo" >
          <h2>{{item.name}}</h2>
          <h3>{{item.reknown}}</h3>
          <p>{{item.bio}}</p>

        </ion-item>
      </ion-list>
      </ion-content>
    </ion-pane>
  </body>
</html>
```

**aap.js file is**

```
 .controller('ListController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http){
    $http.get('js/data.json').success(function(data){
      $scope.artists = data;
    });
    }]);
```

**data.json file is**

```
[
{
  "shortname": "Barot_Bellingham",
  "name": "Barot Bellingham",
  "reknown": "Royal Academy of Painting and Sculpture",
  "bio": "Barot has just finished his final year at The Royal Academy",        
},
{
  "shortname": "Constance_Smith",
  "name": "Constance Smith",
  "reknown": "Academy of Painting and Sculpture",
  "bio": "Smith has just finished his final year at The Royal Academy",        
}
]
```

Comment: ok pankaj will try bro

Comment: it is not working i did that

Comment: are you  getting any erros?

Comment: no i am not getting any errors

Answer (score 0):

here is the working link `http://plnkr.co/edit/soWghwLtwXtjQC1ZnmTC?p=preview`

i found a problem in your JSON file that your data is ending with a comma in each block so your not getting data in to artists
so your json should be like below

```
[
{
  "shortname": "Barot_Bellingham",
  "name": "Barot Bellingham",
  "reknown": "Royal Academy of Painting and Sculpture",
  "bio": "Barot has just finished his final year at The Royal Academy"      
},
{
  "shortname": "Constance_Smith",
  "name": "Constance Smith",
  "reknown": "Academy of Painting and Sculpture",
  "bio": "Smith has just finished his final year at The Royal Academy"       
}
]
```

Comment: i also tried the way you said but again it didn't work

Comment: okay no-problem...can u create a plunker with that.....are you sure that data is in proper format??any errors u can see??

Answer (score 0):

This might not be related to you problem, but you should consider using `then()` instead of `success()`. 
The use of `success()` and `error()` has been depreciated since 1.4.4 i think.

```
$http.get('js/data.json').then(function(data){
  // successcallback
}, function(error){
  // errorcallback
});
```